# JavaScript: Access nested JSON Object

Tags: json, nested

I have a object with below similar structure

```
var obj = {
"9ed4cabcdb1e80d036ec750aaf961959":
    {
        "inputs": {         
            "u_cleanup_source": true,
        },

        "result": {
            "message": "",
            "state": "failure",
        }
    }
};
```

I am trying to access `obj["9ed4cabcdb1e80d036ec750aaf961959"]["result"]["state"]` but `9ed4cabcdb1e80d036ec750aaf961959` changes from request to request. So is there any way to access `result.*.state` despite of having different session Ids.

Thank you.

Comment: Which programming language are you  using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `javascript` the following will work

```
 const keys = Object.keys(obj);
 console.log("ffff", obj[keys[0]].result.state)
```

Comment: Does this solution also works with ES5 as well ? Just checking...

Answer (score 0):

I have found one simple solution as below

```js
for ( var key in obj) { 
  console.log(obj[key]["result"]["state"]);
}
```